# Making a 4x4 widget that uses all available space

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

So after reviewing the guidelines on the developer's guide, I see that a safe 4x4 widget will have a size of 294 x 294 dp. However, on my test device which has a 480x800 screen, it fills it horizontally in portrait but not vertically. The widget that I'm making is intended to fill an entire homescreen, by user request. Of course I know that you cannot entirely fullscreen a widget, but it's supposed to fill up the better part of the 4x4 tiles. As of now, though, it falls short vertically.

What is the best way to make it fill that space? Is there some sort of check that I should do in the actual provider and resize something accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

> The widget that I'm making is intended to fill an entire homescreen, by user request.

That is not possible, sorry.

> What is the best way to make it fill that space?

Try an app widget with a different aspect ratio (e.g., 4x6 in portrait). Off the cuff, I am guessing that the aspect ratio is being maintained, and you are being constrained along the short dimension.

> Is there some sort of check that I should do in the actual provider and resize something accordingly?

You cannot "resize something" on the fly. On Android 3.1, you can create app widgets that the user can resize, though this is mostly for app widgets using `GridView` or `ListView`.

Comment: When I said fullscreen, I just meant that it occupied 4x4 worth of widgets, specifically on a 480x800 display. Using the guidelines, I come up with 294dp for each dimension, but unfortunately, that doesn't fill the space I want it to.

But if I change it so that it's 4x6, are there any devices that I have to now worry about it not working on?

Comment: @michaelgulak: Beats me. I've never considered making an app widget that large.

Comment: There are a lot of Facebook and news related widgets with these dimensions.

Comment: And also, why am I not able to size something dynamically? I could programmatically change the values of the dimensions, no?

Comment: "why am I not able to size something dynamically?" -- because that's not supported.

Comment: So you're telling me that I can't, using RemoteViews, tell a view in a widget to assume a different height based on other conditions? I think we're using differing definitions of "dynamically" here.

Comment: @michaelgulak: You cannot change the height and width of the app widget dynamically. It will take up whatever size you have in your metadata, regardless of what the `RemoteViews` says. Now, if your `RemoteViews` is smaller than what the metadata says, it will render smaller, but the extra space will not be usable by anything other than the wallpaper. And if your `RemoteViews` is bigger than the metadata says, I would expect it to get clipped.